# Javascript loop alert only first index

Tags: javascript, loops, numbers

I have a javascript function like below:

```
function calculateBill(id,price)
{
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty_'+id).value;
    var cur_value =qty*price;    
    var frm_lngth = document.getElementById('bnfsendgoods').length;     
    var fld_length1 = Number(frm_lngth) - 10;       
    var counter = document.getElementById('cntr').value;        
    var fld_length = (Number(fld_length1)) / (Number(counter));     
    fld_length = Number(fld_length);        
    var temp_total = 0;

    alert(fld_length);

    for(var i = 1; i<=fld_length; i++)
    {
        if( i != id )
         {

            alert('qty_'+i); //line 301,alerts only qty_1           

            var temp_q =  document.getElementById('qty_'+i).value;  
    var temp_p =  document.getElementById('ret_price_'+i).value;   //Line 308
            var temp_total1 = temp_q*temp_p;            
            temp_total =  Number(temp_total) + Number(temp_total1);
        }   
    }

    var final_total = Number(cur_value) + Number(temp_total);
    document.getElementById('total').value = final_total;  
}
```

In line 301,the `alert(fld_length);` alerts 8 . if suppose `id = 3` ,acccording to my logic, it should 
alert like `qty_1`, `qty_2`, `qty_4`, `qty_5`, `qty_6` and so on. But it alerts only  `qty_1` . Whats wrong?

Comment: What does `alert(fld_length);` alert ? Some HTML code might also help spot the issue.

Comment: Do you have any supporting HTML?

Comment: `alert(fld_length);` alerts `8`.

Comment: Please check console. (may be in chrome) it is sure that your code breaks after first loop somewhere.

Comment: Are any errors displayed in your browser's console? (Open the console by pressing F12 in IE or Chrome, or press ctrl-shift-K in FF, then try the function again.)

Comment: It says  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null test.html:308`. corresponding html field is like `<input type="hidden" name="ret_price_0" value="20" />`, `<input type="hidden" name="ret_price_1" value="20" />` etc. Line no 308 I have marked in question above

Comment: @Teemo Now I got it..I missed the `id` property there. I will try and inform soon.

Comment: You should not to wrap the following variables in `Number()`: `fld_length1`, `fld_length`, `temp_total`, `temp_total1`, `cur_value` - they already are numbers. You may do so with `qty`, `temp_q`, `temp_p`, though using them in multiplication will convert them implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you have input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ret_price_0" value="20" />
<input type="hidden" name="ret_price_1" value="20" />
etc.
```

These fields don't have an `id` attribute but you are trying to select them by `id` with:

```
var temp_p =  document.getElementById('ret_price_'+i).value;
```

When `document.getElementById('ret_price_'+i)` doesn't find an element with the specified `id` it returns `null`, and then `null.value` gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

Assign appropriate `id` attributes and your code should work. (And be careful, I notice your input's `name` attribute ends in `0` but your loop goes from `1` to `fld_length`.)

And as an aside: you've gotten way too carried away with the `Number()` method - you don't need to use it on variables that already contain numbers. You *should* use it on the values typed by the user (and you should consider displaying an error message if the user enters something other than a number) because when you get an inputs text with `.value` it comes as a string, but you don't need `Number()` *everywhere.*

Answer (score 0):

There may be an exception happening in your for loop, causing the loop to terminate prematurely. Can try to put the code block inside the loop in try/catch so that you get to know what is going wrong.

Comment: A try/catch block isn't necessary if you use the browser's console to debug. But either way this doesn't actually answer the question and so should've been posted as a comment.